# Eclipse skips the newly done code changes when debug

Tags: eclipse, debugging

Am trying to debug a java class in eclipse, but it skips the lines that are added recently.

I have cleaned the cache, started the eclipse in clean mode. but no use.

Thanks in advance

Ranjith

Comment: You may want to give more details. In your case maybe even screenshots...

Answer (score 0):

Possible causes:

- Check you enabled hot code replacement in `Windows > Preferences > Java > Debug`. Select all options in **Hot code replace** group.
- You haven't saved the code. Restarting eclipse/restarting the application is not required if hot code replacement is enabled
- You might have changed the code in other application and debugging some other application.
- You haven't checked the `Project > Build automatically` option.

There might be some other reasons. 
Is the class is on project class-path?Does it have the source(.java file) for it?